# Make pandas to_excel stop styling

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, styling

I'm using Pandas to edit an Excel file which other people are using. But when I save it using `df.to_excel`, Pandas adds an ugly looking black border to cells in the header and in the index. I want it to be written in a plain format, how a CSV file would look if I opened it up in Excel. It would be even better if it was written back using the same styles it was read in

Is there anyway to make `df.to_excel` write without styling or with the original styles?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this trick:

```
import io

pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df.to_csv()), header=None)
  .to_excel("output.xlsx", header=None, index=None)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. Is there any way to style the output your self?

Answer (score 0):

If you still want index and header values - but without styling, you can use this (requires openpyxl):

```
def insert_dataframe(df,sheet,start_row=1,start_col=1):
"""inserts a dataframe into an openpyxl sheet at the given (row,col) position.

Parameters
----------
df : pandas.Dataframe
    Any dataframe
sheet : openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet
    The sheet where the dataframe should be inserted
start_row : int
    The row where the dataframe should be insterted (default is 1)
start_col : int
    The column where the dataframe should be insterted (default is 1)
"""

#iterate dataframe index names and insert   
for name_idx, name in enumerate(df.index.names):

    label_col=start_col+name_idx
    sheet.cell(row=start_row, column=label_col, value=name)
    
    #for each name iterate values as rows in the current index name column
    value_row=start_row+1
    for i_value in list(df.index.values):
        if isinstance(df.index, pd.MultiIndex):
            val=i_value[name_idx]
        else:
            val=i_value
        sheet.cell(row=value_row, column=label_col, value=val)
        #goto next row
        value_row+=1

row_idx=0
col_idx=label_col+1


#insert values
for label,content in df.items():
    sheet.cell(row=start_row, column=col_idx, value=label)
    for row_idx,value_ in enumerate(content):
        sheet.cell(row=start_row+row_idx+1, column=col_idx, value=value_)
    col_idx+=1
```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/Aer0naut/094ff1b6838b2177a4222591ace8f6bf

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).